# Is It Possible to Truncate Empty Grids in Seaborn Facetgrid?

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, seaborn, facet-grid

I am writing code in a Jupyter notebook, and have a Seaborn facetgrid that I want to have 4 columns, and 3 rows. Each plot is for a different country out of a list of 10 countries. Since there are 12 total grids, and the last two are empty, is there a way to just get rid of those last two grids ? The solution of making the dimensions 5 x 2 is not an option since it is too hard to see when so many plots are scrunched together.

Code:

```
ucb_w_reindex_age = ucb_w_reindex[np.isfinite(ucb_w_reindex['age'])]
ucb_w_reindex_age = ucb_w_reindex_age.loc[ucb_w_reindex_age['age'] < 120]

def ageSeries(country):
    return ucb_w_reindex_age.loc[ucb_w_reindex_age['country_destination'] == country].age.fillna(value=30).resample('5d').rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).mean()

def avgAge(country):
    return ucb_w_reindex_age.loc[ucb_w_reindex_age['country_destination'] == country].age.mean()

num_plots = 10
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 4,figsize=(20, 15))
labels = ["01/10", "09/10", "05/11", "02/12", "10/12", "06/13", "02/14"]

list_of_dfs = [{'country': item, 'age': ageSeries(item), 'avgAge': avgAge(item)} for item in ['US', 'FR', 'AU', 'PT', 'CA', 'DE', 'ES', 'GB', 'IT', 'NL']]

colors = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'orange', 'purple', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'orange', 'purple']
col, row, loop = (0, 0, 0)
for obj in list_of_dfs:
    row = math.floor(loop/4)

    sns.tsplot(data=obj['age'], color=colors[loop], ax=axes[row, col])
    axes[row, col].set_title('{}'.format(full_country_names[obj['country']]))
    axes[row, col].axhline(obj['avgAge'], color='black', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=4)
    axes[row, col].set(ylim=(20, 65))
    axes[row, col].set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=0)
    axes[row, col].set_xlim(0, 335)

    if col == 0:
        axes[row, col].set(ylabel='Average Age')

    col += 1
    loop += 1

    if col == 4:
        col = 0

fig.suptitle('Age Over Time', fontsize=30)
plt.show()
```

Facet Grid *I know having images seems to be taboo here in S.O., but theres really not a way to put this in code.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you generate your subplots with

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 4,figsize=(20, 15))
```

not `seaborn.FacetGrid`, as shown in your sample codes. What you need first is to somehow figure out which plots you want to get rid of and what their correct index in `axes`. Then you can use [`matplotlib.figure.Figure.delaxes()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.delaxes) to remove subplots you don't want. Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 4,figsize=(20, 15))
fig.delaxes(axes[2, 2])
fig.delaxes(axes[2, 3])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Delete subplots from `seaborn.FacetGrid` is somewhat similar. The only minor detail is you would access `axes` by `g.axes`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="time", row="smoker", sharex=False, sharey=False)
g.fig.delaxes(g.axes[1, 1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, sorry I guess I am using subplots, and not a facet grid. Your solution worked though ! Thanks Y. Lou

Comment: @TimothyJosephBaney Added codes for `seaborn.FacetGrid` just in case. Please check if needed.